# Entity model outline/border with different color than the material?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I'm looking for a way to make a red box Entity with custom white dotted outlined borders.

I'm really new to RealityKit, is that something I should be able to achieve programmatically?

What I have so far:

```swift
class Box: Entity, HasModel, HasAnchoring {
    convenience init(color: UIColor, position: SIMD3<Float>) {
        self.init()
        model = ModelComponent(
            mesh: .generateBox(size: 0.1)
            materials: [
                SimpleMaterial(color: color, isMetallic: false)
            ]
        )
        position = position
    }
}
```

Comment: @thedb Did you get any success? I am also trying to give border to MeshResource.generateBox. I want to keep the box transparent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That story is about UV-mapping of a model made in 3D authoring tool, or, if you want to do it programmatically, it's about Metal (vertices, edges, faces and uv-vertices). At the moment in RealityKit 2.0 there is no tools to uvmap a border of a model.

You can read about MTLTexture [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/creating_and_sampling_textures).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can I use Metal in a RealityKit scene, or do I have to create a new project with Metal?

Comment: You can use Metal or MetalKit separately or together with RealityKit. Like other Swift modules.